# Save hql query results in csv format

Tags: csv, hadoop, hql, cloudera

This is the code I have used to save my query result to csv file

```
hive -e 'select * from twitter.finalcount' > hdfs dfs /user/hue/resutsofquery/finalcount.csv
```

This is the output:

```
2017-03-18 07:27:40,810 WARN  [main] mapreduce.TableMapReduceUtil: The hbase-prefix-tree module jar containing PrefixTreeCodec is not present.  Continuing without it.

Logging initialized using configuration in file:/etc/hive/conf.dist/hive-log4j.properties
OK
**Time taken: 49.537 seconds, Fetched: 25363 row(s)**
```

But when I check my csv file it wasn't at my directory (resutsofquery). How do I find it? Provide me a good solution

I tried this way too

```
hive -e 'set hive.cli.print.header=true; SELECT * FROM twitter.finalcount LIMIT 0;' > /user/hue/resutsofquery/file_name.csv
```

But it throws an error

> bash: /user/hue/resutsofquery/file_name.csv: No such file or directory

I types this in terminal

Comment: Your syntax makes absolutely no sense. I guess that the results from 1st attempt were dumped in a local file named **hdfs**.

Comment: Looks like you do not know how the Linux shell works, how the shell commands can be piped together, how the input/output/err redirections work, what is a local file system, what is the Hadoop Distributed File system (HDFS), what are the Hadoop Command-Line Interface (CLI) utilities... so there is no point in giving you the correct syntax to do what you want.